# Placing a Sharepoint OpenBinaryStream() into a byte array Csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, content-database

I am able to traverse through my entire Picture Lib, however when I am trying to place into a byte array I am getting an it shows that the value of the OpenBinaryStream(); is empty.  My is to go through the Picture Library and get the image and turn it into a base 64 string.  I should be able to do it by simply placing those bytes into a byte array and then converting it to base 64 but the value is empty.

```
try
{
  var files = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(uri).Files;
  context.Load(files);
  context.ExecuteQuery();

  foreach (var file in files)  << I am traversing my pic lib
  {
    var test = file.OpenBinaryStream(); << when testing the value it is empty
  }
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
            var buf = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Felt my way around this, I found that  `context.Load(file)` , `context.ExecuteQuery()`, was needed to actually load the file, and then I need to proceed into putting it in a stream which I later turned into a byte array which I was able to convert into base 64.

```
public static void GetImage(ClientContext context, string uri)
{
 try
 {
   var files = context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(uri).Files;
   context.Load(files);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in files)
   {
      ClientResult<System.IO.Stream> data = file.OpenBinaryStream();
      context.Load(file);
      context.ExecuteQuery();
      using (System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
      {
        if (data != null)
        {
          data.Value.CopyTo(mStream);
          byte [] imageArray = mStream.ToArray();
          string b64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray);                          
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception exp)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Having same issue using PowerShell, but this answer doesn't work for me.